# Magento 2 : Is there any way to disable Welcome Email after signup

Tags: magento2, customer, email, magento-2.1, customer-account

What is the right approach to disable Welcome Email after completes registration process. I'm using magento2.1. We have an integration with a customer management system and which will sent email to customer after registration. So we need to disable customer welcome email sent by Magento.

I created a custom module to disable mail communication. 
di.xml

```
<type name="\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer">
        <plugin name="disable-email-confirmation" type="Company\Customer\Model\Plugin\Customer" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</xml>
```

Model/Plugin/Customer.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\Customer\Model\Plugin;

class Customer
{
    public function aroundSendNewAccountEmail(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {  
        //$result = $proceed(); 

        return $subject;
    }
}
```

This is not working. I'm still getting emails. 
I see some email communcation refereces inside AccountManagementInterface.

Comment: Why you wanna do that?

Comment: That should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996673/how-to-stop-send-welcome-email-to-customer-in-magento-1-7-0-2

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism `vendor\magento\module-customer\etc\config.xml` What will happen if i comment `<email_no_password_template>customer_create_account_email_no_password_template</email_no_password_template>` ? Can't do?

Answer (score 12):

Create a plugin for \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification. Update di.xml

```
<type name="\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification">
    <plugin name="disable-email-notification" type="Module\Model\Plugin\EmailNotification" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

then create the plugin

```
class EmailNotification
{
    public function aroundNewAccount(\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        return $subject;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i want to send email from my Store1 and not from Store2?

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Here How can I check if customer group. I want set condition on customer group. If customer are retailer we are not sending email.

Comment: Did you got the solution for this?

Comment: `return $subject;` could just be `return;`, for saving memory.

Comment: Please note that this will disable the email confirmation emails too.

Answer (score 0):

You can override below file to disable it.

vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/EmailNotification.php

Look for below function in it.

```
public function newAccount(
    CustomerInterface $customer,
    $type = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED,
    $backUrl = '',
    $storeId = 0,
    $sendemailStoreId = null
) {
    $types = $this->getTemplateTypes();

    if (!isset($types[$type])) {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Please correct the transactional account email type.'));
    }

    if (!$storeId) {
        $storeId = $this->getWebsiteStoreId($customer, $sendemailStoreId);
    }

    $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($customer->getStoreId());

    $customerEmailData = $this->getFullCustomerObject($customer);

    $this->sendEmailTemplate(
        $customer,
        $types[$type],
        self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
        ['customer' => $customerEmailData, 'back_url' => $backUrl, 'store' => $store],
        $storeId
    ); 
}
```

Than comment out lines which are used to send mail.

```
/*$this->sendEmailTemplate(
        $customer,
        $types[$type],
        self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
        ['customer' => $customerEmailData, 'back_url' => $backUrl, 'store' => $store],
        $storeId
    );*/
```

Clear cache and check.

Comment: This is not possible. Because most of propertiesused in this function have orive access. I think create around plugin will  be much better. Or just override this method with epty body.