# Magento 2 - Is there any way to disable Welcome Email after signup for specific store or website

Tags: magento2, email, registration

I have multiple store view setup in my Magento 2 store.

Now I want to disable welcome email for the user that register from the wholesale store. I am trying this solution but it stops sending email to all user.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/174419

I am not getting how to do this for the specific store.

**Update**

I am trying following code

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Model\Plugin;

class EmailNotification extends \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification {

    public function aroundNewAccount(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer,
        $type,
        $backUrl = '',
        $storeId = 0,
        $sendemailStoreId = null
    ) {

        if($sendemailStoreId == 1){
            return false;
        }

        /*$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_storeManager = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager');
        if($_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId() == 1){
            return false;
        }*/

        $result = $proceed($customer ,$type ,$backUrl ,$storeId ,$sendemailStoreId);
        return $result; 
    }

}

?>
```

And getting  error **We can't save the customer.**

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

You should use the create the plugin for the class

> Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification
>   You need to create  plugin on `newAccount`.

create  around method `aroundNewAccount()`  on  `newAccount()` and stop the mail send depend on your store.

```
    public function aroundNewAccount(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification $subject
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer,
        $type = null,
        $backUrl = '',
        $storeId = 0,
        $sendemailStoreId = null
    ) {

        if( $type === null ) {
            $type = $subject::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED;
        }

        if($sendemailStoreId != {YourWHoleSalesStorId}){
            $result = $proceed($customer ,$type ,$backUrl ,$storeId ,$sendemailStoreId);
            return $result
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello Amit, Thanks for the answer. I have tried your code and getting error
We can't save the customer. But customer already saved when i check in admin.

Comment: make `return false` to `return`.updated the answer

Comment: Same error again We can't save the customer.

Comment: Ok, will check the code.

Comment: Thanks, Btw its giving error in front but user is created when checking in admin.

Comment: Please try with last update, i guess it has issue with return type

Comment: Same error. Also tried to add code without my wholesale store view checking and even i am getting error.

Comment: Hello, Amit is there anything you can help me with this issue?

Comment: i am little bit busy. Will implement the code at my local and confirm u

Comment: I am checking now

Comment: @AmitBera could you please help me with the same issue. Path vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\Controller\Account\Emailnotification

Comment: I know, it's an older topic, but if you just return true, it actually works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Do we need to extend the class **\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification** in our olugin class as when i extended this class started getting error We > **can't save the customer**.
If not extending the class then new account email are not sent in all the cases and we need to disable new account email communication for wholesale store only