# new user email notification plugin

Tags: magento2, email

I am trying to send welcome email on signup to store 1 only,but not to store 2.
but the problem is that when i write plugin ,it sends email to none

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139456/magento-2-is-there-any-way-to-disable-welcome-email-after-signup) you need to modified following code

```
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;

class EmailNotification
{
    public function aroundNewAccount(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification $subject, 
        \Closure $proceed
        CustomerInterface $customer,
        $type = 'registered',
        $backUrl = '',
        $storeId = 0,
        $sendemailStoreId = null
    ) {
        if ( $storeId == 1 ) {
            return $proceed($customer, $type, $backUrl, $storeId, $sendemailStoreId);
        }
        return $subject;
    }
}
```