# Magento 2 : Stop sending welcome email

Tags: magento2

Is their any way to prevent sending welcome email to customers from a custom module ?
from a graphql execution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2 : Is there any way to disable Welcome Email after signup](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139456/magento-2-is-there-any-way-to-disable-welcome-email-after-signup)

Comment: The aroundplugin is not recommended to use

Comment: Is their any way it can be implemented without the use of around plugin ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this by custom module with follow link:

https://www.magespark.com/blog/post/how-to-disable-welcome-email-in-magento-2-after-creating-new-customer