# Magento2 - How to NOT send Welcome email when manually adding Customer from admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I want to manually add some customers to the the site via the backend without it auto dispatching a welcome email. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily commented out the code that sends the emails, cleared cache, added the accounts, then uncommented the code, and cleared cache.

I followed some answers here [Magento 2 : Is there any way to disable Welcome Email after signup](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139456/magento-2-is-there-any-way-to-disable-welcome-email-after-signup) to find out where to comment.